# Fresh Install of cakephp3.x gives blank page with PHP code of index.php

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, ubuntu, cakephp-3.0

I am currently trying to install a fresh production installation of CakePHP 3.x. However, for some reason, when I run my localhost, it only gives me "dispatch( Request::createFromGlobals(), new Response() );". When I run the development version using 'bin/cake server', everything runs however.

I have set the webroot of my apache2 in both apache2/apache2.conf and apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf to the webroot directory of my application. Also, I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Does anybody have a clue what causes this? All i can think of, is that it is something with CakePHP itself, but I already redownloaded it using the composer they suggested in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're seeing PHP code, it likely means that PHP is not set up or its not set to interpret the file as PHP and execute it, rather assuming it's plain text and outputting it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the php mbstring extension was missing:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5